# Unrar to same folder structure

Tags: command-line, winrar

Looking for a command do unrar all rar archived but extraction should be in each subfolder

Structure

Parent folder

- Sub folder 1
- - Archive 1
- Sub folder 2
- - archive 2

I have tried this command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" e -r -o- *.rar' from the parent folder. But that extract everything to the parent folder. I want each archive to be extracted to the sub folder. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a bat file with 7 zip instead. worked excellent for my purpose.

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
    FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zg.exe" x -aos "%%X"
    )
popd
)
```